# Вывод данных из html в парсере

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Необходимо вывести порт айпи ":3128"

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'
def get_html(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    return r.text
def soup(html):
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    print(b)
    for link in b.find_all('a'):
        if link.get('title'):
            print(link)
def main():
    result=soup(get_html(url))
    pprint(result)

if __name__=='__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно изменить эту функцию:

```
def soup(html):
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    return [tr.select_one('td').contents[1]
            for tr in b.select('table.proxylist tbody tr')]
```

`b.select('table.proxylist tbody tr')` - находим все строки в таблице.

`tr.select_one('td')` - из каждой строки берем первую ячейку (с IP адресом).

`.contents[1]` - `.contents` возвращает список дочерних элементов. Нам нужен второй элемент - порт.